# ASUS N751JK NVIDIA GTX850M keeps underclocking

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a brand new Asus N751JK which has an NVIDIA GTX850M graphics processor which should be a pretty nice piece of hardware. It runs perfectly fine, and the game I'm playing gives me solid 60 FPS (Cities: Skylines). Now, the bad thing that happens is that the GPU seems to cap itself to 135MHz shader clock speed (absolute value, never goes either above or below when it does this), which makes gaming almost unbearable. The CPU is not doing heavy work at that point (just like at any other point where I get 60FPS) and my RAM usage is perfectly fine. The disk seems not occupied (there is no IO going on) and the power is plugged in. The battery is fully charged aswell.

I tried to find a possible solution to this as it happens completely randomly when I play a game. Sometimes it happens after hours, sometimes after 2 minutes since startup. I tested the speeds with GPU-Z which is known to give accurate results. The temperature has nothing to do with it, as it happens on both cool temperatures and on 80C. 80C does begin the throttling, but that limits it to 1GHz and not to 135MHz.

When I ran furmark, it showed me that limits had power set to 1, which probably means that it's not getting enough voltage (wild guess). What can possibly cause this sudden throttling?

Comment: Are you using ASUS-supplied drivers or the ones from nvidia? If nvidia, try the ASUS one. I did a quick search and found some similar underclocking complaints from September 2014 and the solution was to use the ASUS supplied driver which is dated August 2014. Sometimes OEM hardware differs from the reference design.

Comment: @Yorik I'm indeed using the NVIDIA provided one, so I'll try using the ones provided from the ASUS website.

Comment: This question is confusing you say your getting 60fps so why is the clock being at that speed a problem? Are you saying that the clock throttles itself to that?

Answer (score 0):

- make sure you are running the application on nvidia GPU
- make sure your power plan is balanced or high performance
- you can set power management mode: prefer maximum performance in
  nvidia control panel
- you can disable vsync if you wan to see your gpu work hard and
  generate more frames than your monitors refresh rate. (60 in your
  case)
- new gen cpus and gpus increase their clock speed depending on the
  workload. if you dont experience problems in games you dont need to
  worry about the clock speeds.